# Instance member is not accessible Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

First time using Javascript so it's hard to tell why I get this error. Basically I'm trying to get the functions out of my class module so I can use them for testing, but the functions aren't accessible and I can't see why.

Class(Houselist):

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Card, Table, ButtonGroup, Button, InputGroup, FormControl} from "react-bootstrap";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

module.exports = class HouseList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            houses: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getAllHouses();
    }

    getAllHouses() {
        axios.get("http://localhost:8080/house")
            .then(response => response.data)
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({houses: data});
            });
    }

    render(){
     return //etc
    }
}
```

Test-class:

```
const house = require("./House");
const houseList = require("./HouseList");

const defaultHouse = {
    HouseId: "", Address: "fronttestAddress", HouseNumber: "fronttestHouseNumber", City: "fronttestCity",
};

it('createHouse', function () {
    houseList.getAllHouses() //instance member not accessible, 
                             //but if I make the function `static` I won't be able to use `setState`
    const houseAmount = houseList.houses.length; 

    house.submitHouse(defaultHouse);

    const newHouseAmount = houseList.getAllHouses.length; 
    expect(newHouseAmount).toBeGreaterThan(houseAmount);
});
```

I also tried `import HouseList from "./Houselist"`, but same happens. Why can't I access the function in the `HouseList`-class?

Comment: Given that you mock both of the things you've imported, what's left to test?

Comment: I think you need to initialise your class before you get access to it's member functions. Try `const houseAmount = houseList().getAllHouses().length`.
Another thing: Your method `getAllHouses()` doesn't return anything back, so .length will fail as it is not defined on the datatype `undefined`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Wait so I'm not supposed to use `jest.mock`? Because I tried to look up on how to test classes and the first thing that came up was mocking. Also when I comment the mock stuff out it still gives the same error.

Comment: @YashShah Oh yeah...but how do I access the `houses[]` in `HouseList`? Tried to add `()`, but now it says `unresolved function or method getAllHouses()`

Comment: @Zheng-rongCai, Try houses = `(new houseList()).state.houses`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React components are not supposed to be tested like this. 
You can either use [react-test-renderer](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html) or the best to use [Enzyme](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/)

If u use enzyme, then just shallow render the component like

`shallow(<HouseList {...props} />)`

after this, `componentDidMount` will automatically get called. So before that, add the mocks for your fetch call and test if the mock call has been made or not.

To mock the call, you can use [Axios mock adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter)